# How to do landscape mode on Selenium 4's mobile emulation in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to emulate a mobile browser, and I have this:

```py
    options.add_experimental_option(
        "mobileEmulation", {
            "deviceName": "iPhone SE",
        }
    )
```

which works fine but I also want to do it in landscape mode, so I try:

```py
    options.add_experimental_option(
        "mobileEmulation", {
            "deviceName": "iPhone SE",
            "deviceOrientation": "landscape",
        }
    )
```

but am getting an error saying:

```
from invalid argument: cannot parse mobileEmulation
from invalid argument: 'deviceName' must be used alone
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, but currently this prop hasn't been implemented yet. However, you can define custom device props through `deviceMetrics` and manipulate them as a workaround.

For example, iPhone SE landscape screen resolution has `width` 568 and `height` 320

[Reference](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation)

This code would work:

```py
options.add_experimental_option(
    "mobileEmulation", {
        "deviceMetrics": {"width": 568, "height": 320, "pixelRatio": 3.0},
    }
)
```